# How to track the number of command uses and mentions by the user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just wanted to know if there's a way to count how many times a command has been used in my Discord server **like on screenshot**. 
I'm new with coding. I used discord.js 12.1.1 
Thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTJnu.png)

upd.
for example, **user1** hugs **user2**.

**User1** hugged **N** times

**User2** has been hugged **N** times

how can i make count how many times the message author hugs users?

I tried to insert the count into my finished code, but it only takes into account the mentioned user.

Even if i dont mention anyone, the bot thinks i mention myself..

i tried differently, but my brain is already exploding.. 2 days i cant understand my mistakes

i changed `let member` to different values but it works adequately only all at once.. -_-

dont laugh much, i try(

```js
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const config = require(`../config.json`)
const hugs = require('../db.json');


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
 let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
    let msg =
      member === message.member
        ? `${message.author} hugs everyone`
        : `${message.author} hugged ${member}`;
    let gif = [
      "IRUb7GTCaPU8E",
      "u9BxQbM5bxvwY",
      "3EJsCqoEiq6n6", 
    ];
    let selected = gif[Math.floor(Math.random() * gif.length)];

    let id = member.id || message.author.id
    let hugCount = hugs[id];

    if (!hugCount) {
      hugs[id] = 1;

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
    .setDescription(`${msg}`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setFooter(`${member.user.username} hugged for the first time.`) 
      .setImage(`https://media.giphy.com/media/${selected}/giphy.gif`);


      message.channel.send(embed);

    } else {
      hugCount = (hugs[id] = hugs[id] + 1);

      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
      .setDescription(`**${msg}**`)
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setFooter(`${config.prefix}${module.exports.help.name} | ${member.user.username} has been hugged ${hugCount} times.`) 
        .setImage(`https://media.giphy.com/media/${selected}/giphy.gif`);

        message.channel.send(embed);
      return message.delete()
  }

fs.writeFileSync(
  "./db.json",
  JSON.stringify(hugs),
  (err) => console.log(err)
);

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "hugg"
};
```

and if possible, help  me in this - how to make that the user write a message (for example, !hug user2 **"hello"**) and the bot display message in an embed

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can just have some **database** where you can store `ID` of users and `values` how many times somebody executed you command.

And every time someone uses command you just **increase** `value` for that person `ID` by one.

### Edit #1

I think that this code

```
 hugCount = (hugs[id] = hugs[id] + 1);
```

can be reduce to this:

```
 hugCount = (hugs[id] + 1);
```

And the issue I think is here... Basically you have to know who you need to get. Here you are getting so many thing what you cannot be sure what is inside.

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;
```

So I would suggest to change it to different variables... for example **`let author`** and **`let mentionedUser`** and you need to get both of them in different variables to save both of their counts.

That means you gonna have **user1** who types **`!hug user2 "Hello"`** you need to store in `let author` = `user1` and for `let mentionedUser` = `user2`
And for **each user** you need to have 2 different count values in database (**one** for how many times they hugged someone, **second** for how many times they have been hugged by other person)

I hope this is gonna be helpful.

Comment: but how to make a count of mentioned in the message?

Comment: Just take person mentioned in message and increase some value in his `ID`. Do I get it right, that you want to could how many times someone been mentioned?

Comment: yes exactly
now I will show what I played with. i am very stupid xD and therefore i dont see my mistakes

Comment: @pinkmorning I edited my answer. I hope it's gonna help you

Comment: Oh God, thank you so much, you clarified the darkness in my mind.

I’ll try to do everything now, I hope it works out)

Now i have only 1 question, i can use the database in the form of manually created files or is it better to install some kind of module?

Comment: If I get the question right I would say it's up to you... I kinda don't understand what do you  mean by "modules"

Comment: I didn’t succeed, it does not want to read the id of the mentioned user and 2 embeds are shown separately for 1 command (how many user1 hugged and how many times user2 was hugged). apparently i'm too stupid to make this code, sorry for bothering and thanks for the help <3

Comment: Alright that fine. Try to read this [page about mention arguments](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html) I believe it may help you understand. Basically they are describing there how to split content of message and get only the slice with argument of mentioned user. Personally I mean the **function** `getUserFromMention()`

Answer (score 0):

I use [Redis](https://redis.io/) along side Heroku, to track how many times a command has been used,

> I tried to insert the count into my finished code, but it only takes into account the mentioned user.

> let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.member;

Whose id are you trying to retrieve here?

> Even if i dont mention anyone, the bot thinks i mention myself..
> let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || **message.member;**

message.member is the reason that even when you dont mention anyone, it will get your id.

> how to make that the user write a message (for example, !hug user2 "hello") and the bot display message in an embed

Do you mean the "hello" should be embedded?